# I got ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound only from the second loop in a minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, minitest

I'm running minitest with Ruby on Rails 4.2. I cannot change my framework's version for the moment.
I want to test the mail action for several locales.
So I want to initialize before all tests execution, and I create the user in database via **FactoryBot**.

I want to do this **ony one time** and not before for all tests because it's not performant.

Here the class of my minitest :

```
require 'test_helper'


class PurchaseMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  @@flag = nil

  before do
        unless @@flag
            @@emails = Hash.new
            @@buyers = Hash.new
            @@sales = Hash.new
            I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
                    buyer = FactoryBot.create(:buyer, sale_line_items_count: 1, locale: locale)
                    sale = buyer.orders.first.sales.first
                    email = PurchaseMailer.accepted(sale.id)
                    @@emails.store(locale, email)
                    @@buyers.store(locale, buyer)
                    @@sales.store(locale, sale)
            end
            @@flag = true
        end
  end

    I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
            context locale do

            it 'test_email_to' do
                assert_equal [@@buyers[locale].email], @@emails[locale].to
            end

            it 'test_email_from' do
                assert_equal [ENV['EMAIL']], @@emails[locale].from
            end

            it 'test_of_subject' do
                subject_from_I18n = I18n.t('purchase_mailer.accepted.subject', sale_ref: @@sales[locale].slug, locale: locale)
                assert_includes @@emails[locale].subject, subject_from_I18n
            end
        end
    end

end
```

The first loop **I18n.available_locales** is **ok**, but at time of the second loop I've got the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Sale with 'id'=c0925b6a-4b48-4cb5-9120-03be48187dd
```

During the first loop my test database contains all initialized data,
at the second loop data was erased and I don't figure out why.

I think there is more elegant solution but I want to keep good performance and initialize data only one time.
I've tested a solution based on define_method, but the problem is still the same.

For additional information here my test_helper :

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest"
require "minitest/rails"
require 'factory_bot_rails'
require 'minitest-spec-context'


Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new



class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, first by create two methods in test_helper :

- **begin** to execute only one time the Object creation via FactoryBot and it's ok for performance
- **Minitest:after_run** for database_cleaner

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest"
require "minitest/rails"
require 'factory_bot_rails'
require 'minitest-spec-context'
require 'database_cleaner'

Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

  begin
        @@buyers = Hash.new
        @@sales = Hash.new
    I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|  
            buyer = FactoryBot.create(:buyer, sale_line_items_count: 1, locale: locale)
            @@buyers.store(locale, buyer)
            sale = buyer.orders.first.sales.first
            @@sales.store(locale, sale)
        end
    end

  Minitest.after_run do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

And next part of the solution in the PurchaseMailerTest class is to use into the loop, the **define_method** with the variable **locale** in the name,
instead another style to define test method ('it' for rspec style or 'def' for test method),
as this way there is no more ActiveRecord errors.

```
    I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|

            define_method :"test_mail_to_#{locale}" do 
                assert_equal [@@buyers[locale].email], @@emails[locale].to
            end
...
```